# How to make Custom TabBar with upper curved that stays in Center in SwiftIUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uibezierpath, tabbar, swiftui-tabview

I am new to SwiftUI and have completed half of my TabBar UI. However, I am stuck on adding a minor curve to both sides of the center button, similar to the example image.

[image: Expected TabBar UI]

I'm unsure how to add a minor curve on both sides of the center button? This is what I have achieved so far:

[image: What I have done]

Below is my code for TabBar:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    // MARK: - HIDING NATIVE TAB BAR
    init(){
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            TabBarShape()
                .fill(Color.white)
                .frame(height: 80)
                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.4), radius: 2, x: 0, y: -1)
                .overlay(
                    ZStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            print("Create Button Action")
                        }, label: {
                            Image("plus_icon")
                                .frame(width: 60, height: 60, alignment: .center)
                                .background(Color.custom64B054Color)
                                .cornerRadius(30)
                        }).offset(x: 0, y: -36)
                        Text("Create")
                            .padding(.top, 32)
                        HStack(spacing: 0) {
                            TabBarItem(iconName: "house.fill", action: {})
                            TabBarItem(iconName: "person.fill", action: {})
                        }
                            .frame(height: 80)
                    }
                )
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

 // MARK: - TabBar Shape
struct TabBarShape: Shape {
    // Constants used for the shape
    private enum Constants {
        static let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 20
        static let buttonRadius: CGFloat = 30
        static let buttonPadding: CGFloat = 9
    }
    
    // Function to define the shape's path
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        
        // Move to the starting point at the bottom-left corner
        path.move(to: .init(x: 0, y: rect.height))
        
        // Add a line to the upper-left corner, leaving space for the corner radius
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: 0, y: rect.height - Constants.cornerRadius))
        
        // Add a quarter-circle in the upper-left corner
        path.addArc(withCenter: .init(x: Constants.cornerRadius, y: Constants.cornerRadius),
                    radius: Constants.cornerRadius,
                    startAngle: CGFloat.pi,
                    endAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2,
                    clockwise: true)
        
        // Calculate the end point for the line before the first button
        let lineEnd = rect.width/2 - 2 * Constants.buttonPadding - Constants.buttonRadius
        
        // Add a line to the calculated end point
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: lineEnd, y: 0))
        
        // Add a quarter-circle for the first button
        path.addArc(withCenter: .init(x: lineEnd, y: Constants.buttonPadding),
                    radius: Constants.buttonPadding,
                    startAngle: 0,
                    endAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2,
                    clockwise: true)
        
        // Add a half-circle for the first button
        path.addArc(withCenter: .init(x: rect.width/2, y: 0),
                    radius: Constants.buttonPadding + Constants.buttonRadius,
                    startAngle: 0,
                    endAngle: CGFloat.pi,
                    clockwise: false)
                
        // Calculate the start point for the line after the first button
        let lineStart = rect.width/2 + 2 * Constants.buttonPadding - Constants.buttonRadius
        
        // Add a quarter-circle for the second button
        path.addArc(withCenter: .init(x: lineStart, y: Constants.buttonPadding),
                    radius: Constants.buttonPadding,
                    startAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2,
                    endAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2,
                    clockwise: true)
        
        // Add a line to the calculated start point for the second button
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.width - Constants.cornerRadius, y: 0))
        
        // Add a quarter-circle in the upper-right corner
        path.addArc(withCenter: .init(x: rect.width - Constants.cornerRadius, y: Constants.cornerRadius),
                    radius: Constants.cornerRadius,
                    startAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2,
                    endAngle: 0,
                    clockwise: true)
        
        // Add a line to the bottom-right corner
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
        
        // Close the path to complete the shape
        path.close()
        
        // Convert the UIBezierPath to a SwiftUI Path
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}

 // MARK: - TabBar Item
struct TabBarItem: View {
    let iconName: String
    let action: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            Image(systemName: iconName)
                .font(.system(size: 24))
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .padding(20)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}
```

It would be great if anyone could help. Also Could anyone guide me if this is the correct approach for my expected TabBar UI?

Thank You!

Comment: Why don't you use an image? it can be a vector based image to preserve the quality

Comment: This post might help: [TabBar Customisation in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77126528/20386264)

Comment: I have tried to use an image but for different iPhone devices, it doesn't give the desired result. @MojtabaHosseini

Comment: I already have looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77126528/tabbar-customisation-in-swiftui but the issue is when I flip the central curve to the upper side, the minor curve to is not getting layered. see my result in the question @BenzyNeez

Comment: I believe a proper "slicing" of the image will do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a go at implementing this shape using the same technique of building the path as was used in the answer to [TabBar Customisation in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77127411/20386264) (it was my answer).

I am not familiar with a `UIBezierPath`, so I stuck to `Path` instead.

Here is the revised `TabBarShape`:

```swift
struct TabBarShape: Shape {

    // Constants used for the shape
    private enum Constants {
        static let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 20
        static let smallCornerRadius: CGFloat = 15
        static let buttonRadius: CGFloat = 30
        static let buttonPadding: CGFloat = 9
    }

    // Function to define the shape's path
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()

        // Move to the starting point at the bottom-left corner
        var x = rect.minX
        var y = rect.maxY
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))

        // Add the rounded corner on the top-left corner
        x += Constants.cornerRadius
        y = Constants.buttonRadius + Constants.cornerRadius
        path.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
            radius: Constants.cornerRadius,
            startAngle: .degrees(180),
            endAngle: .degrees(270),
            clockwise: false
        )
        // Add a small corner leading to the main half-circle
        x = rect.midX - Constants.buttonRadius - (Constants.buttonPadding / 2) - Constants.smallCornerRadius
        y = Constants.buttonRadius - Constants.smallCornerRadius
        path.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
            radius: Constants.smallCornerRadius,
            startAngle: .degrees(90),
            endAngle: .degrees(35), // 0
            clockwise: true
        )
        // Add the main half-circle
        x = rect.midX
        y += Constants.smallCornerRadius + Constants.buttonPadding
        path.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
            radius: Constants.buttonRadius + Constants.buttonPadding,
            startAngle: .degrees(215), // 180
            endAngle: .degrees(325), // 0
            clockwise: false
        )
        // Add a trailing small corner
        x += Constants.buttonRadius + (Constants.buttonPadding / 2) + Constants.smallCornerRadius
        y = Constants.buttonRadius - Constants.smallCornerRadius
        path.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
            radius: Constants.smallCornerRadius,
            startAngle: .degrees(145), // 180
            endAngle: .degrees(90),
            clockwise: true
        )
        // Add the rounded corner on the top-right corner
        x = rect.maxX - Constants.cornerRadius
        y = Constants.buttonRadius + Constants.cornerRadius
        path.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
            radius: Constants.cornerRadius,
            startAngle: .degrees(270),
            endAngle: .degrees(0),
            clockwise: false
        )
        // Connect the bottom corner
        x = rect.maxX
        y = rect.maxY
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))

        // Close the path to complete the shape
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}
```

You will notice that there is no need to draw lines between arcs, because they are added automatically.

The smaller corners leading in and out of the main half-circle are drawn as separate arcs. To smooth the join, these arcs and the main half-circle don't go all the way to 90 degrees. These partial angles were found with a little trial-and-error. I also noticed that the height of the half circle in your target screenshot was less than half the height of the button with padding, which is why the center of the + does not align with the top edge of the background area. I used the size of the button padding for this height adjustment and half of the padding for adjusting the x-positions where the small corners begin and end.

Here is how the shape can be used in an adapted version of your main `body`. Some notes:

- An `HStack` with bottom alignment is used to contain the regular tab bar items.
- The + button is shown as an overlay. Space is reserved for the button by adding top padding to the `HStack`.
- Bottom padding is added below the `HStack` to allow for the safe area insets. The insets are measured using a `GeometryReader`.
- The shape is applied as the background. This way, it automatically adopts the size of the frame it is applied to.

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                TabBarItem(label: "Schedule", iconName: "house.fill") {}
                Text("Create")
                TabBarItem(label: "Profile", iconName: "person.fill") {}
            }
            .font(.footnote)
            .padding(.top, 42)
            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                Button {
                    print("Create Button Action")
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus") // "plus_icon"
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .padding()
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .background {
                            Circle()
                                .fill(.green) // custom64B054Color
                                .shadow(radius: 3)
                        }
                }
                .padding(9)
            }
            .padding(.bottom, max(8, proxy.safeAreaInsets.bottom))
            .background {
                TabBarShape()
                    .fill(.white)
                    .shadow(radius: 3)
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
    }
}
```

I also made some small changes to `TabBarItem`, to include a label and omit the padding:

```swift
struct TabBarItem: View {
    let label: String
    let iconName: String
    let action: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            VStack(spacing: 4) {
                Image(systemName: iconName)
                    .font(.system(size: 24))
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                Text(label)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Here's how it all looks:

[image: Screenshot]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank You! Appreciate your efforts :) This works perfectly :) @BenzyNeez

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort, but there is a minor issue with the white horizontal line above the TabBar. Can you please help me remove it? please see the image here: https://ibb.co/TBPCDPz Thank You! @BenzyNeez

Comment: That could be because the content that is scrolling behind the tab bar is not ignoring safe areas. Try adding `.ignoresSafeArea()` to the scroll view. You might also want to add bottom padding to the scroll view, so that it doesn't scroll all the way to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Yes, I added both bottom padding and .ignoresSafeArea() to the scroll view. Thank you so much :) @BenzyNeez have a great day ahead!