# How to make bottom menu with semicircle cut out like shown in Image using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

[image]

I wants to draw shape with curved circle in center using SwiftUI(like above Image), I have tried with following code but was not able to get exactly like above image. Main problem is I had to shift circle to match with corners at edges of circle, which makes uneven padding when circular button is placed.

```
struct CurvedShape : View {
let r1 : CGFloat = 10
var body : some View{
    
    Path{path in
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 55 - r1))
        
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width  - r1 , y: 55 - r1), radius: r1, startAngle: .init(degrees: 0), endAngle: .init(degrees: 90), clockwise:false)
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + r1 + 30, y: 55 - r1), radius: r1, startAngle: .init(degrees: 90), endAngle: .init(degrees: 180), clockwise: false)
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: 55 - r1), radius: 30, startAngle: .init(degrees: 0), endAngle: .init(degrees: 180), clockwise: true)
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - r1 - 30, y: 55 - r1), radius: r1, startAngle: .init(degrees: 0), endAngle: .init(degrees: 90), clockwise: false)
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: r1 , y: 55 - r1), radius: r1, startAngle: .init(degrees: 90), endAngle: .init(degrees: 180), clockwise:false)
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 55 - r1))
        
    }.fill(Color.green)
    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 180))
}
}
```

Result of above code is image below(except icons and button in center), which has uneven paddings.
[image]

Comment: These posts might help: [TabBar Customisation in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77126528/20386264), [How to make Custom TabBar with upper curved that stays in Center in SwiftIUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77689977/20386264)